# is the volume of an irregular tetrahedron calculated in the same way as a regular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, volume

Most of the tetrahedrons I've seen have been regular and those I've seen that have been irregular I never had to do anything with. So I'm just curious.

Comment: A tetrahedron is a cone, so it's volume equals the one-third product of the area of its base times its height.

Comment: A regular tetrahedron inscribed in a cube has a volume equal to 1/3 the cube, which makes it a snap.  But it is a pyramid with triangular base.  And $\frac13 b h$ will work for any pyramid.

Comment: @DougM ok thanks